# How to get all the repositories for a particular user?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, bitbucket

I am trying the extract the various repository names for a particular user and populate a combobox on a html page. I am able to extract only one repository name. How can I get all the names? The code I have so far:

```
$.ajax({
        url:"https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/abc",
        username: "palld@bdbd.in",
        password: "abcdef123456",
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(){
            console.log("Connection did not go through");
        },
        type: 'GET'
    });
```

Writing similar code in Java and python worked and I was able to see all the repository names. Any help would be appreciated.

The result is as below:
[image]

Comment: How many repository names do you get while calling via Java / python? Did you cross check to make sure the URL is the same?

Comment: Yes. I get around 8 repositories while calling via java/python. The url is exactly the same as the one I use in Java and python

Comment: So what is the value of `console.log(data)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Edit:

It appears that Bitbucket will send you some data even when you are not authenticated to their API. I suspect that there is no authentication request sent to you by the API and jQuery simply does not send the username and password when not asked for.

This code explicitly send the authentication data to the API:

```
var reposUsername = "OWNER_OF_REPOS";
var authUsername = "YOUR_USERNAME";
var authPassword = "YOUR_PASSWORD";

$.ajax({
    url:"https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/" + reposUsername,
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(){
        console.log("Connection did not go through");
    },
    type: 'GET',

    headers: {
        'Authorization': "Basic " + btoa(authUsername + ":" + authPassword)
    }
});
```

(I'm 100% sure that this code works as I've tested it a few minutes ago with my own Bitbucket account).

**Note:** please be aware that storing your credentials in the code is something you should not do, so think twice before you release your code/application the the public.

---

#### Obsolete answer:

Just look at the [documentation](https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/resource/repositories/%7Busername%7D) Bitbucket provides to you (although, the example response looks kind of weird).

Assuming your `data` object is already a JSON parsed object, you should be able to access your respositiories like this (**Edit**: code adjusted the the provided screenshot):

```
data.values
```

Comment: I am taking the URL from the documentation and no problem with Java/python. Only with JavaScript

Comment: What exactly do you get as a result of the request?

Comment: An object with an array of repositories and their details

Comment: I meant what does ``console.log(data)`` return (you can paste the result on a pastebin or in the main question)?

Comment: data stores a JSON object

Comment: Please read again my updated answer, I've tested this on my account and it successfully returned all my repos.

Answer (score 0):

Parse the JSON response. If it works from Python or Java then it must be something to do with the way you are handling the response in JavaScript. Perhaps you are not parsing it, which you need to do to convert it into a proper JSON object containing all the elements you want.

```
success: function(data){
    console.log(JSON.parse(data));
},
```